# Why do I get cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++, gcc4

```
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
/usr/bin/make  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cppapplication_1
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d
g++ -arch i386   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 311ms)

simpatico$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10/4.5.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Configured with: ../gcc-4.5.1/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc45 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc45 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.5 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.5 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc45/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-fully-dynamic-string
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.1 (GCC)
```

This simple of a file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: How did you build gcc - 4.5.1 is not a standard Apple one

Comment: using macports: sudo port install gcc45

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `-arch` option is part of the Apple extensions to `gcc`.  You need to use the `gcc` supplied by Apple's Developer Tools, `Xcode`.

Comment: MrRoy: What does `which g++` and `g++ --version` show?  The first should be `/usr/bin/g++` and, with current Xcode 4.6.3 on OS X 10.8, the latter should be `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `-arch` option is only in the Apple-provided version of `gcc`. Change `CFLAGS` (which might be set via your environment, your makefile, or your configure options) so it uses `-march` or `-m32` instead. For example:

```
configure CFLAGS='-m32 -O2' CC=gcc-4.5
```

The difference seems to be that you can specify multiple `-arch` options to generate universal binaries, whereas `-march` only generates one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The macports version of GCC doesn't support the -arch flag.  As it turns out Apple's GCC is a wrapper around the real gcc that honors a few special flags before calling the real compiler.  The -arch flag is one of these flags.  It calls the appropriate compiler for each of the archs specified and then uses lipo to mash all of the object files back together into a "fat" object file.

I just spent a little bit of time getting this Apple GCC wrapper working with macports GCC.  If you want the details you can find them here:

http://thecoderslife.blogspot.com/2015/07/building-with-gcc-46-and-xcode-4.html

Answer (score 1):

This error exists in many forms, regardless of the machine or build type.
The solution, in general, is to change the PATH and CROSS_COMPILE variables to include the correct cross compiler.