# When I "make" valgrind, I got error

Tags: c, valgrind

```
Andy@Macbook-Pro~/test/valgrind-3.6.1$ make
make  all-recursive
Making all in include
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in VEX
make  all-am
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I.. -I../include -I../VEX/pub -DVGA_amd64=1 -DVGO_darwin=1 -DVGP_amd64_darwin=1 -Ipriv   -arch x86_64 -O2 -g -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-format-zero-length -fno-strict-aliasing -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -fno-stack-protector -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-long-long  -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-stack-protector -MT libvex_amd64_darwin_a-main_globals.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libvex_amd64_darwin_a-main_globals.Tpo -c -o libvex_amd64_darwin_a-main_globals.o `test -f 'priv/main_globals.c' || echo './'`priv/main_globals.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
make[3]: *** [libvex_amd64_darwin_a-main_globals.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And this is end part of message after I do "./configure"

```
   Maximum build arch: amd64
     Primary build arch: amd64
   Secondary build arch: x86
               Build OS: darwin
   Primary build target: AMD64_DARWIN
 Secondary build target: X86_DARWIN
     Default supp files: exp-ptrcheck.supp xfree-3.supp xfree-4.supp darwin10-drd.supp darwin10.supp
```

Need help.
Thank you

Comment: which version of gcc do you have? also the problem described in this question might apply to you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391192/why-do-i-get-cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-arch

Comment: Sounds like a memory error. You might try using valgrind to find it. (okay, no it doesn't, but I couldn't resist)!

Answer (score 1):

You need [`valgrind` 3.7.0](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html) to build on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.x), and the UR reports that it will build on Snow Leopard (10.6.x) too.  It is known that `valgrind` 3.6.1 does not build on Mac OS X Lion.

There was an earlier version that built on Snow Leopard, but it is long enough ago I don't remember for sure the version numbers.  The [news](http://valgrind.org/info/news.html) page indicates that in July 2010, there was initial support for Mac OS X Snow Leopard.  I believe that was in `valgrind` 3.6.0.  I still have 3.6.0 installed, though I should delete it since it does not work on Lion.  I was unable to get 3.6.1 to work, but that may have been a problem on Lion (and I was distressed for a while until 3.7.0 was released).