# OS X choose llvm gcc compiler

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compilation, macports

TLDR: I want to use the llvm compiler, not some other gcc compiler that I installed using macports.

Whilst trying to compile a c++ library, I ran into this error:

```
c++: error: unrecognized option '-arch'
```

After searching on SO, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391192/why-do-i-get-cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-arch) post which indicates that the `'-arch'` option is part of Apple's extensions to gcc.

A while ago I installed a different GCC version, using Macports, in order to compile some tools for some other software. Now when I check this, I can confirm that it is using the version from Macports:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (MacPorts gcc46 4.6.4_3) 4.6.4
$ which g++ --version
/opt/local/bin/g++
```

Using `port select` only yields two options,

```
$ port select --list gcc
Available versions for gcc:
    mp-gcc46 (active)
    none
```

So I can't change the default compiler here. Where can I change this to use the llvm compiler in `/usr/bin/`?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler that comes with LLVM is Clang, not GCC. Have you got XCode 5 installed? And the command line tools as well? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/831673) explains how to install them quite clearly.

Then you can try to run `clang --version` to verify that clang has been installed properly and is available in the command line. Then to compile with auto-tools, you can pass it in the CC and CXX variables as @paul-roub said:

```
CC=clang CXX=clang++ ./configure
make
```

Bear in mind that Apple is using a modified version of LLVM/Clang. They used to use GCC before but they dropped the support for it when the license changed to GPLv3 if I remember correctly. On a clean 10.9 install with XCode 5.1 you shouldn't have GCC at all though, it's been completely replaced by Clang.

Answer (score 1):

Configure scripts and Makefiles will often respect the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables, telling them to use a specific compiler.

e.g.:

```
$ CXX=/usr/bin/g++ CC=/usr/bin/gcc ./configure
$ CXX=/usr/bin/g++ CC=/usr/bin/gcc make
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this a permanent change? I'm also trying to install something using `python setup.py install` and not a makefile .

Comment: You can add `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++`, etc. to your `.Profile`, but that may mess up other things. I'd hope the Python setup tools would also respect these variables, but haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to select `none` to go back to the default compiler.
If no gcc compiler is selected using macports (and therefore, no link called gcc exists in `/opt/bin`) then the first gcc compiler encountered will be the one in `/usr/bin`.